# 'I'm glad I look like my mother'

Tags: words

How would you say it in Japanese? 「母みたいでよかった」？If not, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「[母]{はは}みたいでよかった。」 ***could*** mean "I am glad I look like my mother.", but without any context to explain that you are talking about the physical resemblance, it would usually just mean "I am glad I **am** like my mother."

To express "I am glad I **look** like my mother." in a single sentence all by itself, you would say:

「[母親似]{ははおやに}でよかった。」

Kids would say 「お[母]{かあ}さん[似]{に}でよかった。」 and they can say it to anyone.  Because of the word 「お母さん」, adults can say that only when talking to other family members.

Comment: Is there a difference between 母親似で and 母親に似てて?

Comment: @Sjiveru no, there is none.